# Multiple URLs in multiple browsers in selenium (local) python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, browser-automation

I have a test script that I want to be run for multiple URLs on multiple browsers (Chrome and Firefox) locally on my machine. Every browser has to open all the URLs for the test script. I have run the test script for multiple URLs for multiple browsers. I have the following code which do the task. Is there any better way to do this code? Thank you

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver_array = [webdriver.Firefox(), webdriver.Chrome()]
sites = [
    "http://www.github.com",
    "https://tribune.com.pk"
]


for index, browser in enumerate(driver_array):
        print(index, browser)
        for index, site in enumerate(sites):
            print(index,site)
            browser.get(site)
            time.sleep(5)
            # localitems()
            # sessionitems()
            # def localitems() :
            local_storage = browser.execute_script( \
                    "var ls = window.localStorage, items = {}; " \
                    "for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
                     "items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k);"\
                    "return items; ")
            print(local_storage)

            # def sessionitems() :
            session_storage = browser.execute_script( \
                    "var ls = window.sessionStorage, items = {}; " \
                    "for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
                    "items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k);"\
                    "return items; ")
            print(session_storage)
```

Comment: I am assuming you are asking for parallel execution with cross-browser testing. You can achieve this using 'pytest' unit testing framework.

Comment: @AbiSaran Can you share an example in the case of the above code? Since I don't have enough idea about pytest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python Selenium solution for handling parameterization with multiple browsers in parallel.

`pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "-n2"])

class TestBrowser():
    @parameterized.expand(
        [["chrome"], ["firefox"]]
    )
    def test_parameterized_browser(self, browser):
        driver = Driver(browser=browser)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.quit()
```

It will open up two different browsers in parallel, which will close after 3 seconds. If the drivers aren't already on the System PATH, they will automatically be downloaded, but it will take some additional seconds for that.

This next script expands on that to handle more args for parameterization (based on your example):

```py
from parameterized import parameterized
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "-n4"])

class TestBrowser():
    @parameterized.expand(
        [
            ["chrome", "https://github.com"],
            ["firefox", "https://github.com"],
            ["chrome", "https://tribune.com.pk"],
            ["firefox", "https://tribune.com.pk"]
        ]
    )
    def test_parameterized_browser(self, browser, url):
        driver = Driver(browser=browser)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.quit()
```